# Is the javascript import statement enough to get CurvyCorners working, or do I have to add more?

Tags: javascript, css, curvycorners

Okay, I have looked hard for this answer, but all the websites, even the CurvyCorners homepage, don't say it clearly enough.  Is the `<script type="text/javascript" src="curvy.corners.trunk.js"></script>` statement enough to get `border-radius` on Internet Explorer using CurvyCorners, or do I have to do more?

Comment: By reading the instructions it seems like importing the .js script and defining the CSS it's enough: ["As from 2.0.x, CurvyCorners allows you to put rounded corners on your page elements using CSS."](http://www.curvycorners.net/instructions/) Have you already tried?

Comment: I suspected that, but I tried doing it and it didn't work.

Comment: Could you maybe provide us with the developed CSS? And what browsers did you use in testing?

Comment: There's no need to provide you with code.  All I did was import the javascript file, and set the border radius of an object.  I used IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be enough, here is an example: http://www.curvycorners.net/includes/examples/demo4.html (have a look at the source)